# Пропадают права администратора

Tags: java, android

Я разрабатываю приложение, которое требует права администратора. **Android 5 Lolipop** все работает нормально, а на 5 **Android** после того как пользователь дал права и перезагрузил девайс - права пропадают! Как это можно исправить? Приложение при этом не перенесено на SD карту!

Comment: `Android 5 Lolipop` и `5 Android` - это одно и то же. Определитесь, где работает, а где - нет

Comment: @metalurgus, До Android 5.0 все работает.